# Como ejecutar repositorio con código en JavaScript, HTML, Y CSS que convierte numeros binarios a decimales en windows 10?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación tengo un ejercicio para resolver hallé un repositorio de un conversor de números binarios a decimales en javascript, HTML y CSS que busqué en github tengo windows 10 pero no tengo la menor idea de como ejcutarlo... ese es el repositorio. https://github.com/guilhermemorningstar/ConversorBinarioDecimalJs

alguien que me pueda ayudar?.. Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lee por favor [ask]

Comment: Hola podes editar tu pregunta y agregar mas informacion? cual es tu repositorio y cual es tu environment windows, mac, linux? Gracias!

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado con las etiquetas usadas, java no es lo mismo que JavaScript

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero primero identifiques si quieres algo en Java o JavaScript; no es lo mismo. Ahora, prueba descargando e instalando NetBeans para usar ese repositorio (ya local en tu compu).

Comment: si es javascript, vas a necesitar una ide o un servidor web que pueda ejecutar dicho codigo.. el codigo js no es ejecutable dentro de windows por si mismo...

Comment: Bueno lo primero que debes hacer es tener todos tus arhivos localmente. Si podes clonar ese repositorio en tu PC o vas a tener que descargarlos manualmente y despues es cuestion que abras el index en tu navegador. y listo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Descarga de Repositorio

1. Abre el link de Github y del lado derecho encontraras un botón que te permite descargar el zip con los archivos

[image: Screenshot]

2. Descomprime, según tu sistema operativo puedes o no hacerlo sin descargar un programa (entiendo que win10 no requiere que instales nada, solo haz click derecho y extraer). Si no tienes ya instalado un programa para descomprimir un zip puedes descargar 7zip.

[7zip Official](https://www.7-zip.org/)

Es open source y altamente reconocido.

3. Mueve la carpeta que se generó a algún lugar de acceso sencillo, puede ser tu escritorio.

## Ejecución

4. Puedes ver que la carpeta descargada y descomprimida sólo tiene un CSS (hoja de estilos), un JS (fichero de código Javascript) y un HTML. Por lo tanto este proyecto esta pensado para abrirse en un browser (Chrome, Internet Explorer - Edge, Safari, Firefox, etc)
5. Abre el archivo index.html (que está en la carpeta descomprimida) en tu browser de preferencia. Listo, tu proyecto esta corriendo

[image: Screenshot]

**Nota:** Si abres firefox puedes arrastrar el archivo index.html a la pantalla y este se abrirá en una nueva tab.